# Primefaces Snapshot 4.0 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/component/menuitem/MenuItem

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I tested primefaces-4.0-20130907.101718-6.jar with tomcat Server Open Source Edition 8.0 rc1 and javax.faces-2.2.3.jar. I get this exception:

> java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Source Document:
>   /WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-extensions-1.0.0-20130720.041214-62.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
>   Cause: Class
>   'org.primefaces.extensions.component.masterdetail.MasterDetailRenderer'
>   is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/primefaces/component/menuitem/MenuItem

What is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Well your missing a runtime dependency :-) Give us some more information. SO we can answer the question now we are only guessing. Do you use Maven? Did this project always work etc etc

Comment: It seems your jars are not compatible with each other or your application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly the extensions version you have is not compatible with PrimeFaces Core version you have.